# Browser doesn't remember file path when doing multiple uploads

Tags: browser, file-upload, uploadify, plupload

I allow multiple images to be uploaded to my site.  They click "Choose Image" and then are presented with a dialog they can use to select an image from their disk.  The image gets uploaded and then they can choose another.  However, the next time that they click "Choose Image", they have to re-navigate to their images folder.  This makes it not much fun to upload many images.

I am currently using Uploadify, but the user says that the same problem occurs when uploading sample images using the Plupload demo page.

The user is using Windows 7 and IE9.  I am also using Windows 7 and IE9 and am not experiencing the issue.  I have full admin rights with UAC turned off, so maybe that has something to do with it?

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Should this question be posted on SuperUser instead?

Comment: I'd really like to know the answer to this too. I have the same problem with Uploadify, Win 7, IE9

Comment: Since i cant see or test anything ill just have to take a random shot, but a common 'fix' ive been seeing regarding IE9 is to just force IE8, add this:
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >
In your <head> tags and see if that helps.

Comment: Looks like someone has submitted a bug report to uploadify for just this. http://www.uploadify.com/forum/#/discussion/9251/file-select-not-remembering-previous-file-path/p1

Comment: That was me. My previous bug report (unrelated) has not been answered as of yet though so my hopes for this one are low too :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting. I found a [post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/how-do-i-get-internet-explorer-9-to-remember-the/84c6c128-1173-4050-b2ba-52b5edb8c0e6?msgId=e1ab00da-0050-4a86-96b3-7d464a2f9cc3) on the Microsoft Answers site that seems to suggest adding the site to your trusted sites fixes the problem (for that site)

```
Internet Options > Security > Trusted Sites
```

Running Win7 and IE9, I got the same behavior from the Uploadify demo. Adding uploadify to my trusted sites, closing the window and re-opening solved it.

Comment: Hmm, I can't test it right now unfortunately and the bounty is ending soon, but I'll do my best to test it in time. Although it isn't a solution I can sell to my client, it is a reason for a "won't fix" to give to the client (i.e. a security issue within the browser).

Comment: I just booted into Win7 and tested it using the Uploadify demo and it works. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: My new working theory is that uploading to a secure host might fix the issue for everyone. I'll let you know if I find anything to substantiate this.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately neither seem to work for me. You are the only answer here however so I guess the bounty is going to you anyway. Thanks for taking the effort to solve this problem!

Comment: Ignore that last comment, after restarting IE it works like a charm! Still not a solution for my clients problem but at least clarity on what's causing this. Here, have some points.

Comment: Yeah I had to close and reopen the tab